# Using scala spark how to print just the response body value returned from a HTTP post call

Tags: scala, apache-spark, http-post-vars

I have a flask application that returns the following if I do a cURL to it:

The response is in a **JSON format** as follows:

```
{"your_field": "hello there buddy"}
```

I want to get just the value "*hello there buddy*" and print it. Any idea how to do it?

I have the following code:

```
def myExampleFunction  = ( text: String ) => {

  val result = Http("http://localhost:5001/other/post").postData("{\"my_field\":\"" + text + "\"}")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
    .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000)).asString

  println("result.body is!! : " + result.body)
  result.body
```

Running this prints the following:

`result.body is!! : {"your_field": "hello there buddy"}`

What I want to achieve is:

`result.body is!! : hello there buddy`

Comment: I don't have env set up but, result. your_field would work

Comment: COMPILE ERROR: value your_field is not a member of scalaj.http.HttpResponse[String]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.body` is of type `string`, parse string data to json data to extract the required field.

In below code I have used `json4s` library to parse string response to json data.

```
  def myExampleFunction  = ( text: String ) => {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    val result = Http("http://localhost:5001/other/post")
      .postData("{\"my_field\":\"" + text + "\"}")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .header("Charset", "UTF-8")
      .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(10000))
      .asString

    (parse(result.body) \\ "your_field").extract[String]
}
```

Comment: If I use parse(result.body \\ "your_field" and pass to a variable and print it. It then just prints `JString()` - instead of `hello there buddy` - any idea why?

Comment: I have updated answer .. you have call .extract[String] to extract string values. let me know if its not working